# How do I resolve "g++.exe: error: dsa: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, g++

I have the following file, `dsa trials.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    std::cout << "Hello world!";

    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to compile it, I get the following error message:

```
PS E:\cpp codes> cd "e:\cpp codes\" ; if ($?) { g++ dsa trials.cpp -o dsa trials } ; if ($?) { .\dsa trials }
g++.exe: error: dsa: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: trials.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: trials: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Why can't I compile and run this simple "Hello world" program?

Comment: Easiest solution here is to remove the space from your source filename. You can see from the error message that it's providing _two_ files to compile. One is named `dsa` and one is named `trials.cpp`. Obviously you wanted `"dsa trials.cpp"`. So either rename the file or edit the build configuration to enclose filenames in double quotes. Similar treatment is required for your output, which as you can see also needs quotes for both the build and execution.

Comment: Note for future: Provide actual compiler output as _text_ in your questions. This makes it more easily readable, and more importantly _searchable_.

Comment: rename your source file so it doesn't have spaces in it. For example, replace the space with an underscore.

Comment: Whatever "IDE" you are using: ditch it. It cannot even get spaces in filenames right.

Comment: @Jaymin The `E: \cpp codes>` prompt indicates that you run on Windows. The native IDE Visual Studio Community has handled this non-problem since forever. Using Linux tools on Windows is definitely not user friendly.

Comment: @paddy you should post your comment as an answer: it's a real solution for a real problem (albeit a basic one).